# Connecting and running esp8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I am trying to connect my ESP8266 to my computer to program it. However, I cannot even get passed the first step. Do not get the ready message to pop up.

Currently I have the 5v of the Arduino connected through a 1K ohm and then a 2k Ohm resistor to the VCC, the CH_PD and the reset pins on the ESP. The GPIO pin 0 is grounded and the ground is as well. The TX of the Arduino is connected to the RX of the ESP and the RX the Arduino is connected to the TX of the ESP through a 1K ohm and then a 2K ohm resistor.

I tried Arduino IDE, I've tried Putty, and even flashing it. Nothing works.

- When running the Arduino IDE and you run the serial port, then type AT, nothing shows up in the box.
- When using the method print to serial it prints `AT` but nothing is returned.
- When using a flashing program it either says failed or cannot connect to device.

Right now there is a blue light and a red light on at all times.

Comment: First off, _which_ ESP8266 ([some comparison](http://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/) of devkits)? On Instructables there are tons of [ESP8266 plus Arduino IDE tutorials](http://www.instructables.com/id/Blink-for-ESP8266-native-like-arduino-using-Window/). I never found the resistors necessary to get me started.

Comment: Its the -01. I read A LOT of them! and every one is different. some say put gpio 0 to ground some say put reset up and CH_PD up and some say the exact opposite. some say during restart do this and during flashing do this. during regular do that. just a confusing. I did get it to work putting 3.3v from the arduino to the esp, the ground to ground and the tx to tx and the rx to rx. I connected it to my network and i got it running. However, I unplugged it and plugged it back in and now it will not turn on on 3.3v on 5v it will turn on, but no response. I think I may have burned it, but not sure.

Comment: "I may have burned it" - if you really hooked it up to 5V that's very likely I'd say. Connecting GPIO0 to GND is to put the device into flash mode. Then you reset / reboot the device, flash, disconnect GPIO0 from GND and reset / reboot again. VCC+CH_PD have to be connected to 3.3V. [squix](http://blog.squix.org/2014/12/esp8266-using-seeeduino-to-talk-to.html) is a trusted source ([here](http://blog.squix.org/2014/12/esp8266-flashing-lua-firmware-and.html) as well).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot power up `es8266` using voltage divider, whenever you connect `VCC` to `CH_PD`, your `VCC` will pull down to very low voltage. You need to power your `esp8266` using **3.3v**, not 5V, nor voltage divider. You can connect 3.3V of your `Arduino` to `esp8266`.